# Soil Data WFS accepting request in WGS84 but not in NAD83

Tags: wms, wfs, soil

Soil Data has two WFS servers. https://sdmdataaccess.nrcs.usda.gov/WebServiceHelp.aspx

I have made a successful URL to request from WGS84 server:

https://sdmdataaccess.sc.egov.usda.gov/Spatial/SDMWGS84GEOGRAPHIC.wfs?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetFeature&VERSION=1.1.0&TYPENAME=mapunitpoly&SRSNAME=EPSG:4326&BBOX=-121.9246584917641627,36.86446939088204289,-121.60054248356131268,37.09945349682910631

But when I am trying to do the same for NAD83 one. The server is replying bad request.

> Error getting BBOX and extent area from WFS request string (shorthand BBOX filter) Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Can someone figure out what I am doing wrong?

https://sdmdataaccess.sc.egov.usda.gov/Spatial/SDMNAD83GEOGRAPHIC.wfs?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetFeature&VERSION=1.1.0&TYPENAME=mapunitpoly&SRSNAME=EPSG:42659&BBOX=-121.9246584917641627,36.86446939088204289,-121.60054248356131268,37.09945349682910631

These two links have a description of the request format:

https://sdmdataaccess.nrcs.usda.gov/WebServiceHelp.aspx

https://sdmdataaccess.sc.egov.usda.gov/Spatial/SDMNAD83Geographic.wfs

Comment: Try changing the axis order of your bbox

Comment: @IanTurton tried that ... didn't work

Comment: What is EPSG:42659? I guess that it should be EPSG:4269 but the service does not accept it. I would contact the service provider.

Comment: Yes, the service has other issues as well, it should be 4269 but it is 42659. But I don't think this issue is what causing bad request? @user30184 Do you think they both are related?

Comment: Because EPSG:42659 probably does not exist it could well be the reason for the error `Error getting BBOX and extent area from WFS request string`.